# Check if the stored procedures contain correct table names

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, runtime-error, tablename

I got MySQL database from my client and it has lot of stored procedures. The problem is that some of the stored procedures contain wrong table names (table names that do not exist). So is there a mechanism I can find those wrong table names in stored procedures?

Comment: I don't think there is any mechanism for that because its runtime error if table not found

Answer (score 0):

Check whether table exist or not using following command.

`SHOW TABLES LIKE 'yourtable';`

If table exist then it will return table name,if not exist then it will return 0 row.

Comment: He dont want to do it manually. He wants to compare `foreach(entry in table.column) if entry == existing table => Show tables`. Unfortunately I cant get it using joins.

Comment: Ok then write only `SHOW TABLES`

Comment: how will i get table name from store procedure and where you have to implement it means in query or store procedure

Comment: I want to run a query or something that checks every stored procedure uses correct table names